# How to Convert a 24bit WAV file to 32bit while keeping Audio Format PCM = 1 (linear quantization)

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, wav, sdl-2, sox

Refer Here for more context to my question: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/136817/how-to-get-sdl2-to-play-32bit-wav-files

I have a 24bit WAV file that has an Audio Format PCM of 1, refer here: http://soundfile.sapp.org/doc/WaveFormat/ to `AudioFormat`

When converting my WAV file (24bit) to 16 bit using: `ffmpeg -i input.wav -ar 48000 -ac 2 -acodec pcm_s16le output.wav` it retains the Audio Format PCM = 0x001.

When using `ffmpeg -i input.wav -ar 48000 -ac 2 -acodec pcm_s32le output.wav` the Audio Format PCM = 0xfffe.

SDL2 (as seen in the parent question) only allows files to play with Linear PCM Audio Format (1), and I am unsure how using `sox` or `ffmpeg` how to convert my 24bit WAV files upwards to 32bit (as SDL2 only plays 32bit and 16bit).

Is what I'm asking possible? Some more information on WAV files and why ffmpeg changes the header number would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FFmpeg uses the following code to set the codec tag

```
...
waveformatextensible = (par->channels > 2 && par->channel_layout) ||
                       par->channels == 1 && par->channel_layout && par->channel_layout != AV_CH_LAYOUT_MONO ||
                       par->channels == 2 && par->channel_layout && par->channel_layout != AV_CH_LAYOUT_STEREO ||
                       par->sample_rate > 48000 ||
                       par->codec_id == AV_CODEC_ID_EAC3 ||
                       av_get_bits_per_sample(par->codec_id) > 16;

if (waveformatextensible)
    avio_wl16(pb, 0xfffe);
...
```

---

A crude attempt would be to just replace the 2 bytes at 0x20 with `01 00` and try. If that doesn't work and this behaviour is out-of-spec then file a [bug report](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/).

Comment: I will try manually editing the hex of the file and seeing if that allows it to be played through normal means. I notice some bug reports on ffmpeg regarding some similar issues with format extensible. With that line particularly, (> 2 channels = false, sample_rate > 48k = false, av_get_bits_per_sample > 16 = true (possibly, I'll have to look into that function / macro)), so I'll play around with it and get back.

Thank you for looking into this.

Comment: Using Vim to edit the hex of bytes 20 and 21 of the WAV header from `fe ff` (0xfffe) to `01 00` (0x0001) allows SDL2 (parent post) to play the signed 32 bit little endian audio perfectly.

Not sure how to go about reporting this as a bug, but maybe there is a reason for the "extensible wave format" although I've never heard of it.

Comment: I believe it is SDL2 at fault here. The original WAVE spec only allowed 8 and 16 bit samples. The newer spec allows greater sample depth and rates. Bug report should be filed with SDL project.

Comment: I've made a post here: https://forums.libsdl.org/viewtopic.php?p=52656#52656 asking for more advice on the matter, but yes, I will be reporting a bug or making a pull request (to fix it can be adding another constant and switch case I believe, not that hard).

Comment: Note in the original gamedev post, this bug has been fixed in SDL2 recently, probably not available in package managers, but it indeed has been fixed as of yesterday.